# Watson Assistant action to call IBM Cloud Function fails with Direct CloudFunctions calls are not supported on this platform

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, openwhisk

We are trying to implement cloud functions in Watson conversation but am receiving message 'Direct CloudFunctions calls are not supported on this platform'. When I googled for the error, I see that the issue could be because the region for WA and the cloud functions are different or not in US South/Germany. But I can confirm that both my WA and cloud functions are in US South.

I was trying in the 'Try out' panel. Below is the mock json editor content for my dialog node.

```
{
  "context": {
    "my_credentials": {
      "user": "jgjg",
      "password": "khk"
    }
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "response text"
      ]
    }
  },
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "/<myIBMCloudOrganizationID>_<myIBMCloudSpace>/get-http-resource/weather", 
      "type": "server",
      "parameters": {
        "location": "Austin"
      },
      "credentials": "$my_credentials",
      "result_variable": "$my_result"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can you pls advise me on what am I doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I assume that my_credentials was set, correct? What is the URL of your WA environment?

Comment: @data_henrik - yes. my_credentials are set in the same context. You can see in the json above. This is my workspace url(browser console)

https://assistant-us-south.watsonplatform.net/us-south/xxxxxx/workspaces/xxxxxxxxxxx/build/dialog#node=Welcome

Answer (score 1):

I was going through the same issue. Cloud functions are only available in some regions. If your app is hosted in sydney or somewhere you cannot use that service there. Create a new app and set the location to london

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your user and password are set correctly?

Your user should consist of LETTERS and NUMBERS and some HYPHENS. like so : ...a-32d7-7d...
Your password should be just a string ...gafhWhu6alirEVpD...

Both are found in your api key on your IbmCloudFunctions page : https://console.bluemix.net/openwhisk/learn/api-key

Username is before the : of the api key and

Password after the : of the api key

If you already know this then i'm afraid i dont know how to help you.

Best